# Fetching an array of ID's with promise.all() not working

Tags: reactjs, fetch, request-promise

I am making a series of api requests to return objects based on their id, using promise.all().
However, i'm getting 404's, which I think is due to the way i've added my headers (as i tried with another simpler API that doesn't need authentication and it works fine).

The API i am accessing is the UDEMY api. Documentation here: https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/

Can anyone help me make this work with the headers?
Thanks.

```js
getCourseData = () => {
  let courseIDs = this.state.beginnerCourseIDs;
  
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode("XXUSERKEY:XXSECRETKEY"))

  let requests = courseIDs.map(course => { 
    return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/${course}/, { headers: ${headers} }` )
  });

  Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => responses.forEach(
    response => console.log(response)
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your headers object is forming part of your url string.

You will need to add your headers to the options object, the second argument to **fetch**:

```
let requests = courseIDs.map(course => { 
  return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/${course}/`, { headers })
});
```

Also, if the API returns JSON then you will need to parse the response as a JSON object:

```
let requests = courseIDs.map(course => { 
  return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/${course}/`, { headers })
    .then(res => res.json())
});
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.